# How to filter object-like union types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, mapping, union-types

Let's say that I have 3 types and a union type of them:

```
type Cat = {
  owner: string;
  color: string;
  lives: number;
}

type Dog = {
  owner: string;
  color: string;
}

type Wolf = {
  color: string;
}

type Animals = Cat | Dog | Wolf;
```

I want a filter `AnimalsFilter<U, K>` that would work like this:

```
type FilterAnimals<U, K extends string> = ...;

type WithOwner = FilterAnimals<Animals, 'owner'>;
// WithOwner = Cat | Dog
```

So that after filtering this union type it would only have Cat and Dog. How can I achieve that?

I tried mapping, like this:

```
type FilterAnimals<U, K extends string> = {
    [Key in keyof U]: Key extends K? U[K] : never;
}[keyof U];
```

But it does not work as intended. Am I even close to answer with this?

Comment: Another way of doing it, besides the answer:
`type FilterAnimals<T, K extends string> = T extends { [P in K]: any } ? T : never;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `HasKey<T, K>` as a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `T` into its members, then perform another conditional check via `keyof` to just keep those members with a key from `K`.  Like this:

```
type HasKey<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends unknown ? K extends keyof T ? T : never : never;

type AnimalsWithOwner = HasKey<Animals, "owner">;
// type AnimalsWithOwner = Cat | Dog
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsKBeKBvAUFKB7A7gOwgCcAuKAZ2CIEt8BzAbkygGNsAbbUiq2x59tQBuEcmXwBXALYAjYkwC+6dKEhQAItjrI0zPIW6Ua9JljadDvE+iUrw0AOocAZjoxmOXMkb6Llq6ABBfGopOHZyHXhEAB8NLSg4p3ZnJjs1AAk4cgBpCBAAHgAVABooHKgIAA9gCHwAE0iABSJsSCJQPJAAPmRmIsqausaoCXwAa3x9KAB+csHahsjx-OxXAbmB8QgRIiht3bSAqGDQ8PIHamAACwB5AmIdLNz8gtOwiLKAIn1iL+6mAB6QFQY7vc6XG73AxRBCJeJ0dBAA)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! But I cannot understand the role of unknown and a second never here. Could you please clarify?

Comment: `type G<T> = T extends unknown ? F<T> : never` is a *distributive conditional type* that causes `G<T>` to be `F` distributed over unions in `T`, so that `G<X|Y|Z>` is `F<X> | F<Y> | F<Z>`.  The `never` is simply required because something must go there, `T extends unknown` will never be false.  We're not trying to check anything, just distribute unions. See documentation for distributive conditional types linked in the answer.